# How to initialize a nested dictionary within a class?

Tags: python

I am completely lost on how to initialize the following attributes within a class. The initializer should create a new log giving the date and data starting at 0 hours

```
_date: date
_data: Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]  #{branch, {employees, hours}}
_branch: List[str]
_employees: List[str]
hours: int
```

Class `__init__()` method:

```
def __init__(self, date: date) -> None:
    self._date = date
    self._data = {}
    self._branch= []
    self._employees= []
    self.hours = 0
```

Comment: What is the format of the this `log`? What does it have to do with a nested dictionary?

Comment: I need a dictionary of all braches of a company, each brach corresponding to a list of employees and how many hours they've worked. I've called the class log since it is for tracking all of the information pertaining to employee hours

Comment: Well, the `self._data = {}` **is** initializing the `data` attribute to an (empty) dictionary—what more do you want?

Comment: The main question is from where do you take the data about employees? Once we know that, we may help you to pass those in your class.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but it seems to me that you want to know how you can send the rest of the information to the class so you can store it in some instance variables. Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a dictionary with no contents with:

```
var = dict()
```

To initialize a dictionary with literal data, use:

```
var = {
   'key_1': {
       'nested_key': 'nested_value'
   },
   'key_2': {
       'nested_key': 'nested_value'
   }
}
```

If you have some sort of default value you need on every key, use:

```
from collections import defaultdict
var = defaultdict(list)
```

Does that answer your question?